# How to overwrite channel permissions with bitfield

Tags: discord, discord.js

I tried to get my bot to save channel permissions but it only saves its bitfield. Can I somehow overwrite channel permissions for a specific role only using the bitfield?

I tried doing something like this:

```js
channel.overwritePermissions(role, {
  permissions: perms
});
```

and then tried changing it to:

```js
channel.overwritePermissions(role, {
  bitfield: perms
});
```

It just puts `/` for every permission.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/general/welcome) of the stable branch, the use of [`GuildChannel.overwritePermissions()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions) is different from yours:

```js
GuildChannel.overwritePermissions(your_role, {
  VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
  SEND_MESSAGES: null,
  PERMISSIONS_WRITTEN_IN_THIS_FORMAT: true
});
```

In order to convert the bitfield to a permission name, you can use [`Permissions.FLAGS`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS), an object that contains all the bitfield values for every permission. Here's the current one:

```js
{ CREATE_INSTANT_INVITE: 1,
KICK_MEMBERS: 2,
BAN_MEMBERS: 4,
ADMINISTRATOR: 8,
MANAGE_CHANNELS: 16,
MANAGE_GUILD: 32,
ADD_REACTIONS: 64,
VIEW_AUDIT_LOG: 128,
PRIORITY_SPEAKER: 256,
VIEW_CHANNEL: 1024,
READ_MESSAGES: 1024,
SEND_MESSAGES: 2048,
SEND_TTS_MESSAGES: 4096,
MANAGE_MESSAGES: 8192,
EMBED_LINKS: 16384,
ATTACH_FILES: 32768,
READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY: 65536,
MENTION_EVERYONE: 131072,
EXTERNAL_EMOJIS: 262144,
USE_EXTERNAL_EMOJIS: 262144,
CONNECT: 1048576,
SPEAK: 2097152,
MUTE_MEMBERS: 4194304,
DEAFEN_MEMBERS: 8388608,
MOVE_MEMBERS: 16777216,
USE_VAD: 33554432,
CHANGE_NICKNAME: 67108864,
MANAGE_NICKNAMES: 134217728,
MANAGE_ROLES: 268435456,
MANAGE_ROLES_OR_PERMISSIONS: 268435456,
MANAGE_WEBHOOKS: 536870912,
MANAGE_EMOJIS: 1073741824 }
```

To get the name of the permission, you can simply work backwards:

```js
function getPermName(bitfield = 0) {
  for (let key in Discord.Permissions.FLAGS) 
    if (Discord.Permissions.FLAGS[key] == bitfield) return key;
  return null;
}
```

Once you got the name, you can use it as shown above.

Comment: Yes but i dont know how to get the boolean variables for a specific role i can only get the bitfield so if there is a way of overwriting permissions using the bitfield without the boolean variables.

Answer (score 0):

To find the name of the permission returned by a simple bitfield.

```js
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');
const simpleBitfield = 2048n;
Object.entries(Permissions.FLAGS).find(p => p[1] == simpleBitfield);
// outpout: [ 'SEND_MESSAGES', 2048n ]
```