# how can i display permission overwrites before and after updating the channel

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot and I'm trying to log channel updates I was able to log name updates but I couldn't figure out how I can log overwrite changes like this [if anyone can tell me how these work I would really appreciate it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jj4qZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the information if there's any update in channel using the client event [channelUpdate](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-channelUpdate). This function requires two parameters, `oldChannel` and `newChannel`. In your case, these two returns a [GuildChannel](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel). GuildChannel has a property [permissionOverwrites](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=permissionOverwrites), which would return the collection of updated set of permissions of a role or a member of that channel. You can use `<GuildChannel>.permissionOverwrites.each()` to get all the collections.

**Note:** It will return bitfield values.
So to check with bitfield values, you can have a look, at the answer of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52580903/how-to-overwrite-channel-permissions-with-bitfield).

Comment: Glad to help you!!